# How do I arrange from smaller to bigger value for x?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
  for(int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < distance.length; j++) {
            if (distance[i] == distance[j]) {
                if (x[i] > x[j]) {
                    x = swapInt(x, j, i);
                    input = swapString(input, j, i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

distance represents the distance of a point from the origin
x is the x coordinate for the points
input is the original input of the points by the user
i want this loop to arrange the points in ascending order for the x coordinate if their distance is the same
however, when i run it, it arranges in descending order
what should i do to solve this?

```
 public static int[] swapInt (int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: how come a single array of primitive is storing both x and y coordinate

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (x[i] > x[j]) {
```

to

```
if (x[i] < x[j]) {
```

This will change the sorting order: in the original you swap two values if the i'th is larger than j'th, now you swap them when the opposite is true: j'th is larger than i'th

Answer (score -1):

I will prefer the following way as it is more clean, readable.

```
class Distance implements Comparable{
int x;
int y;
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Distance other=(Distance)o;
    if(this.distanceFromOrigin() > other.distanceFromOrigin())
        return 1;
    else if(this.distanceFromOrigin() < other.distanceFromOrigin())
        return -1;
    else 
        return this.x - other.x;

}
int distanceFromOrigin(){
    return x*x+y*y;
}
```

}

Now create of an array/list of Distance and use Collections.sort to get your desired order.